# Can NOT update table in SQLite

Tags: qt, sqlite

I'm using an update query into SQLite database but keep getting this error and I can not understand where am I going wrong.`Failed   QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")`
This is how I've created the table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS singleSetting (set_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date DATETIME,"
    "password VARCHAR(255), unique_column VARCHAR(2) UNIQUE, logo BLOB, title VARCHAR(50), print_dialog INTEGER(1),"
    "staffImageDir VARCHAR(255),visitorImageDir VARCHAR(255),camera INTEGER(1),host VARCHAR(50),database VARCHAR(50),"
    "username VARCHAR(50),pass VARCHAR(50),port INTEGER(10));
```

My code, I have tried converting the port into QString but that doesn't work either.

```
QString host = ui->lineEdit_host->text();
QString database = ui->lineEdit_database->text();
QString username = ui->lineEdit_username->text();
QString password = ui->lineEdit_password->text();
int port = ui->lineEdit_port->text().toInt();

//QString p = QString::number(port);

QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare( "UPDATE singleSetting SET host = '"+host+"', "
              "database = '"+database+"', username = '"+username+"', "
              "pass = '"+password+"',port = '"+port+"' WHERE unique_column = '0'" );

if( !qry.exec() )
{
    qDebug() <<"Failed  "<< qry.lastError();
}else{
    qDebug() <<"Success";
}
```

Comment: If you choose to use prepared queries anyway, you should use parameters/bind values like in the [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#prepare).

Comment: `Failed   QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")` now i'm getting this error after using bindValue `qry.prepare( "UPDATE singleSetting SET host:host,database:database,username:username,pass:password,port:port WHERE unique_column = '0'" );
    qry.bindValue(":host", host);
    qry.bindValue(":database", database);
    qry.bindValue(":username", username);
    qry.bindValue(":password", password);
    qry.bindValue(":port", port);`

Comment: You can show how you have created the connection to the database.

Comment: `Database::ibtDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
 Database::ibtDB.open();`

Comment: Where do you indicate the path of the database?

Comment: `QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase( "QSQLITE" );
    db.setDatabaseName("/path/of/your_database.db");
    db.open();`

Comment: That's all done in `Database` class.

Comment: I just tried it and it is working correctly. Does your database have data?

Comment: generated the same error if the database had no data or did not match the condition: unique_column = '0', and that behavior is normal since it indicates that I did not find any row with that condition.

Comment: If you want us to help you share your database and your project through drive, dropbox, github or similar.

Comment: Using parameters works like `UPDATE singleSetting SET host = :host, database = :database, ...`. Notice the `=`!

Comment: Thank so much `db.setDatabaseName("/path/of/your_database.db");` it wasn't fetching the database path some unknown reason. Would you like to make this as an answer so I can accept it.